# writing to strings inside a structure doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, list, function, struct

I have an issue with my code, I changed a few of the functions to accomodate the structure I added, so instead of having variables all over the place, but now it does not work at all. I need it to create a structure person, then it prompts the user to enter the persons name, and age; then it asks for more persons to fill a doubly linked list which stops the loop if nothing is input for the persons name. THEN it spits out the reverse of what I input into the doubly linked list. All help is appreciated ^-^

```
struct person
{
    char name[10][41];
    int age[10];
};

int write(struct person *people);
void print(struct person *people);
int main(void)
{
    char names[10][41];
    int n = 10;
    int ages[10];

    typedef struct person people;

    n = write(people);
    print(people);


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


int write(struct person *people)
{
    int i;
    char name[41];
    int age[10];
    for(i=0; i<=i; i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter full name\n");

        gets(people.name);
        strcpy(names[i], name);

        if(names[i][0] == '\0')
            break;

        printf("Enter their age\n");
        scanf("%d", &age[i]);
        ages[i] = age[i];
    }
}

void print(struct person *people)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(names[i][0] == '\0')
            break;

        printf("%s is %d year(s) old\n", names[i], ages[i]);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: What is this: `for(i=0; i<=i; i++)` ?

Comment: was using it to test my loop, didnt want to change it until i knew it worked

Answer (score 0):

1. You are passing the name of a type that you just defined instead of a variable declared of that type, this

   ```
   typedef struct person people;
   ```

   should be

   ```
   struct person people;
   ```
2. Change

   ```
   n = write(people);
   ```

   to

   ```
   n = write(&people);
   ```
3. Remove `fflush(stdin)` it's undefined behavior.
4. Do not use `gets()` it's very unsafe, use `fgets()` instead

   ```
   char name[40];
   gets(name);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   char name[40];
   fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
   ```